# GraphQL returning no errors but undefined

Tags: graphql, gatsby

Have been searching for a while. I am using Gatsby and I have no errors in the console or terminal but values are undefined. Could it be because of the second "data" under "articles"?

GraphiQL Query:

[image]

Query/Component Code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { graphql } from 'gatsby'

// This query is executed at build time by Gatsby.
export const GatsbyQuery = graphql`
  {
    umdHub {
      articles {
        data {
          title
        }
      }
    }
  }
`

class ClientFetchingExample extends Component {
  render() {
    const {
      umdHub: { articles },
    } = this.props.data

    console.log(articles.title)
    return (
      <div style={{ textAlign: 'center', width: '600px', margin: '50px auto' }}>
        <h1>{articles.title} - Is the title of the article</h1>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default ClientFetchingExample
```

Comment: It is not clear what plugin do you use for adding `umdHub` to graphql schema. Could you or add link to the plugin or add `gatsby-config.js`?

Comment: ^ that `umdHub` might be the problem? You're not using it in the graphiq editor? Also from your graphql it looks like `articles` contains a `data` object which contains an array of `titles`, however you're accessying `articles.title`. Perhaps try `articles.data[0].title`

Comment: I am using gatsby-source-graphql and umdHub is my fieldName

Comment: does your query work in the GraphQL Playground?

Comment: I think `articles` returns array not object, so you have to `console.log(articles);` instead, then iterate on them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already halfway there just small changes

```
const {
      umdHub: { articles },
    } = this.props.data
```

Now you have this articles object like this

```
articles: {
    data: [
        { 
          title: 'Learning to Listen'
        },
        { 
          title: 'Second Title'
        }
        ...
    ]
}
```

Now you need to loop over data

```
import _ from 'lodash'
const data = _.get(articles, 'data', [])

_.map(data, title => {
    console.log({ title })
})
```

If you want to only first title then

```
const title = _.get(articles, 'data[0].title', 'default value or blank string')
```

Here lodash is A modern JavaScript utility library delivering modularity, performance & extras.